# Пользовательская функция суммы в зависимости от значений в строке

Tags: javascript, функции, google-apps-script

Функция перебрает масив.

Условия:

1. Проверка счета на совпадение, если совпадают и поле ФИО заполнено напротив двух совпадающих счетов количество выездов плюсуются.
2. Если совпадают счета но поле ФИО  заполнено напротив одного, то выводит количество выездов напротив заполненного ФИО.
3. Если не совпадают и поле ФИО заполнено выводит кол-во выездов.
4. И если не заполнено ФИО и счет дублируется/не дублируется то Вывод 0

Ниже вариант, но никак не могу разобраться, как корректно записать данные в Таблицу

```
function departure() {
  function convertToSimpleArray(array){
    var res=[];
    for (var i=0; i<array.length; i++)
     if (!Array.isArray(array[i]))
      res.push(array[i]);
     else
      res=res.concat(convertToSimpleArray(array[i]));
     return res;}

  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var sheet = ss.getActiveSheet();

  var invoices = sheet.getRange("B2:B14").getValues();
  var surnames = sheet.getRange("C2:C14").getValues();
  var qts = sheet.getRange("D2:D14").getValues();

  var invoice = convertToSimpleArray(invoices);
  var surname = convertToSimpleArray(surnames);
  var qt = convertToSimpleArray(qts);

  for (var i = 0; i < invoice.length; i++) {
   var numberOfqt = 0;
   for (var j = 0; j < invoice.length; j++) {

    if (invoice[i] == invoice[j]  && surname[j] != null && i != j ) 
     numberOfqt += parseInt(qt[j]);

    if (invoice[i] != invoice[j] && surname[j] != null) 
     return qt[j];
   }
    return numberOfqt;
  }
```

На выходе пытаюсь получить это:
[image: Визуализация]

Comment: Пример бы почетче. Где точка входа? Какие аргументы передаются? Зачем `convertToSimpleArray` ?

Comment: точка входа - var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet(); аргументы - invoice, surname, qt. convertToSimpleArray - конвертирую многомерный масив в одномерный, так как цикл работал не корректно.

Comment: Ок, подойдем проще. Как вы вызываете скрипт?

Comment: путем ввода в ячейку формулы =departure()

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Необходимо оперделиться с точкой входа. Пользовательские формулы требуют данных на входе. Не советую использовать `getValues` и все такое.

```
/**
 * Выводит что-то
 *
 * @param {Range} scheta - Колонка счетов.
 * @param {Range} fios - Колонка ФИО.
 * @param {Range} vizovy - Колонка вызовов.
 * @param {Number} row - Вывести для конкретной строки.
 * @return что надо.
 * @customfunction
 */
function departure(scheta, fios, vizovy, row) {
  try {
    if (!((scheta.length == fios.length) == (vizovy.length == fios.length)))
      return '#SIZEOF';

    var stack = {};
    for (var i = 0; i < scheta.length; i++) {
      var schet = ("" + scheta[i][0]) !== "" ? scheta[i][0] : "undefined";
      if (!stack.hasOwnProperty(schet)) {
        stack[schet] = {
          once: true,
          sumFio: 0,
          sumEmpty: 0,
          hasFio: false,
        };
      } else {
        stack[schet].once = false;
      }
      if (fios[i][0]) {
        stack[schet].sumFio += vizovy[i][0];
        stack[schet].hasFio = true;
      } else {
        stack[schet].sumEmpty += vizovy[i][0];
      }
    }

    if (row && row > 0) {
      var schet_ = ("" + scheta[row - 1][0]) !== "" ? 
        scheta[row - 1][0] : "undefined";
      return stack[schet_].hasFio ? stack[schet_].sumFio : 0;
    }

    var res = [];
    for (var i = 0; i < scheta.length; i++) {
      var row = [];
      var schet = ("" + scheta[i][0]) !== "" ? scheta[i][0] : "undefined";

      var item =
        stack[schet].hasFio ? stack[schet].sumFio : 0;

      row.push(item);
      res.push(row);
    }
    return res;

  } catch (err) {
    return err.message;
  }
}
```

Для следующих данных

[image: Данные]

- `=departure(A2:A13,B2:B13,C2:C13)` вернет расчет для всего массива
- `=departure(A2:A13,B2:B13,C2:C13, 1)` вернет расчет для строки 1 и указанного массива

[Скопировать файл с решением](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1wcoDlLDvec3LdJzOmbWwMO1PdZaZu21rDyXMJIxgP5I/copy)